# error when selecting row from db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select data from a certain row in a my sql db. This is the code im using:

```
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die('connection error '.mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('selection error '.mysql_error());

$select = mysql_query("SELECT FROM WordPress_theme_customers WHERE ". "GDI_Username = '$sponsor_GDI_id' AND Unique_id = '$sponsor_refference'");


while($check = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $sponsor_email = $check["Email"];
    $sponsor = $check["GDI_Username"];
    $sponsor_first_nme = $check["First_Name"];
    $sponsor_second_nme = $check["Last_Name"];
    $sponsor_domain = $check["GDI_Domain"];
    $unq_id = $check["Unique_id"];
 }
```

I keep getting this error:
"Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /SC/sponsor.php on line 10"

line 10 is: `while($check = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {`

I've made sure the db info is correct including the table name, still nothing.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has a syntax error, causing `msyql_query()` to return a boolean FALSE, not a result handle. Try doing:

```
$sql = "SELECT FROM WordPress_theme_customers WHERE ". "GDI_Username = '$sponsor_GDI_id' AND Unique_id = '$sponsor_refference'";
$select = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . "<br>" . mysql_error());
```

Putting the query into its own variable lets you examine it separately, and the `or die(...)` will tell you exactly why the query failed.

The syntax error itself is here:

```
SELECT FROM WordPress_theme_customers
      ^--- here
```

you are not specifying any fields to retrieve. At minimum, it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

Comment: hey i just tried that (the 8 inbetween select and from). still says the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your SQL query it should be SELECT * or SELECT some column name.

Answer (score 0):

This warning generally means that there's been an error during the execution of the SQL query -- and `mysql_query()` didn't return a valid result-resource.

You can use [**`mysql_error()`**](http://www.php.net/mysql_error) to find out what error is caused by your query :

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT FROM WordPress_theme_customers WHERE ". "GDI_Username = '$sponsor_GDI_id' AND Unique_id = '$sponsor_refference'");
if (!$select) {
    // this is for debugging -- you don't display an error and die
    // in a portion of code that goes on a production server !
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
```

Here, the problem is that **you didn't specify which fields should be selected** : you should add a list of field to select between `select` and `from` :

```
select name_of_field1, name_of_field2 from ...
```

Or, to select all the fields, use a `*` :

```
select * from WordPress_theme_customers WHERE...
```